# Serializer returns media files URLs in http not in https in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize a model and one of its fields is a FileField
when calling serialiser.data it returns the URL of the FileField in an HTTP schema, not an HTTPS.

Here is my code

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='')


class FileSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = '__all__'

def files_list(request):
    files = File.objects.all()
    serialiser = FileSerializer(files, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serialiser.data)
```

I get

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "demo",
"file": "http://domain-name.com/media/image.png"
}]
```

I want it to be

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "demo",
"file": "https://domain-name.com/media/image.png"
}]
```

I'm using Nginx and set

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
```

Then in your Django settings added the following:

```
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

And the problem is not fixed, what should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current request needs to be passed to the serializer [in the context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) so that your FileField can determine the correct protocol

```
serializer = FooSerializer(foo_instance, context={'request': request})
serializer.data
```

Comment: I've already done that in my example, but it does not work.

Comment: @MUHAMMEDATIF can you add the code from your example that is generating your output to your question (the view, serializer and model)

Comment: I've updated the question. check it.